# NSString to char (not const char)

Tags: objective-c

How can I convert `NSString` to `char`? Note - `char` not `const char`. I have float number, I need to convert it so that only 2 values after `.` would be left. So I use NSString to do that. After that I need to make NSNumber from that. So I decided to convert NSString to char and after that to NSNumber. So I tried

```
char* someCharINeed = [SomeString UTF8String];
```

And it says

```
Cannot initialize a variable of type 'char *' with an rvalue of type 'const char *'
```

If it is used like that

```
const char* someCharINeed = [SomeString UTF8String];
```

it works but NSNumber

```
[NSNumber numberWithChar:someCharINeed];
```

says

```
Cannot initialize a parameter of type 'char' with an lvalue of type 'const char *'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than converting to a string, another way to do this is to multiple the number by 100, convert the answer to an int and then divide by 100 -- that will give you 2 places after the decimal point.

```
float newValue = floorf(oldValue*100)/100;
```

Comment: But doesn't int removes anything whats after `.`? I mean wouldn't it happen like this:
 int smth = 124.146334;
 smth = 124
when I need to get value
 smth = 124.14?

Comment: That's why you multiply by 100 first.  20.1234 X 100 = 2012.34 --> convert to int = 2012. Divide by 100 = 20.12